# evaluate an string with a variable name inside it

Tags: php, variables, eval

i have an string as a field value stored in a table like : `"abc".$_GET["param1"]`
if `param1` is set to `"123"`, is there a way to make a variable such as `$file="abc123"` by using some thing like eval or {} ?

Comment: I dont understand teh question ,you want a variable $abc123; ?

Comment: What is wrong with doing just `$file = "abc" . $_GET['param1'];`?

Comment: i want a $file with "abc123" value becomes from $x='"abc".$_GET["param1"]'  when param1 is "123" ( $_GET["param1"]=123 get from url)

Comment: Read about [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), though you're probably taking the wrong approach to your real problem

Comment: look at $x, "abc".$_GET["param1"] is a qouted value.

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you’re almost certainly asking the wrong question." - Rasmus Lerdorf, PHP's creator and BDFL

Answer (score 0):

i find an answer for my question :

```
$x='abc$_GET[param1]';
$file = eval('return $file="'.$x.'";');
```

the above code set $file = "abc123" when param1 in url is 123.